# global variables in php mess my html up!

Tags: php, html

I have a problem. When I use global variables in my php code, my server doesn't show any html code at all. If I comment out the global variable, my html page works just fine! Am I doing something wrong here?

php file:

```
class DBConnect{

    // If I comment this out, the HTML shows
    global $con;

    function connectDB() {
        $user = "bstokni_basurin";
        $pass = "basurin";
        $database = "basurin";
        $host = "localhost";

        $this->$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Connected to MySQL </br>";
        echo $con;
    }

    function closeDB() {
        mysql_close($con);
        echo $con;
        echo "MySQL closed";
    }   
}
```

html file:

```
<!-- Left colon -->
            <div id="leftCol">
                <p>Her kemur ein menu at standa</p>
                <?
                    $menuObj = new DBConnect();
                    $menuObj->connectDB();
                ?>
            </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're getting a PHP error but the errors are suppressed. Put this at the top of the page and tell us what you get `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @Mike Swift - It could also be that styles are just hiding the error or warning. @hogni89, have you tried selecting the text in the vicinity of the problematic div, or tried installing custom error handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the variable is in a class scope, try changing `global` to `public` instead. You don't seem to need global in the example you have provided.

Comment: And it's probably not expected, meaning it's (as Mike Swift points out) throwing a suppressed error. Here's a proof: http://codepad.org/b5JsmgPx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to class in PHP. 
I had two problems. First of all:
$this->$con = ...
should be:
$this->con = ...

And changing from global to public also worked :) I can go to sleep now ;)

Comment: Add `function __construct() { global $test; }` and change `global $test;` in your current project to `public $text;`. It will set the variable as global when the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't:

```
$this->$con
```

be:

```
$this->con
```

?

If you're just trying to access a member variable named `con`. Everywhere else you refer to is by just `$con`, why the `$this` in the one place? I'm not sure what `$this->$con` is supposed to do, but I'm guessing it is affected by whether or not `$con` has been declared global.

Comment: `$this->$con` will try to access the public variable named whatever the value of `$con` is. See [this example](http://codepad.org/CKU7XB2Y). In his case, `$this->$con` is some MySQL resource that will probably be wrongly interpreted as a string.

Comment: Ya the extra $ will blow it up every time.  But you need to checking your errors too, so do as suggested by mike swift as well.

Comment: I had a feeling. But the contents of `$con` would be `null` in both cases, wouldn't they? So `$this->$con = ...` should be assigning to the same (wrong) place whether there is a `global $con` declaration or not. So how does one case work and the other not?

Comment: `global` isn't correct to use as a class variable (I misspoke earlier, it doesn't matter that it's a public or private variable in this case, just a class variable), that's what the error was. In my case, I'm only assigning one class variable; it only prints the one it knows about.